# Crawl Spider for nested webpages doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

Below spider doesn't crawl web site, I would like to know if I used wrong code to crawl multiple pages within same web site.
**Here is the code TestScrpy.py :**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class CraigslistSampleItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    date = scrapy.Field()
    description=scrapy.Field()

class SiteSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "newscrap"
  #download_delay = 2
  allowed_domains = ['example.com']
  start_urls = ['http://example.com/page/1']
  items = {}


def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    #requests =[]
    brands = sel.xpath("//div[@class='thumb']")
    for brand in brands:
        item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        url = brand.xpath("./a/@href")[0].extract()
        item['url'] = brand.xpath("./a/@href")[0].extract()
        item ["title"] = brand.xpath("./a/@title").extract()
        item ["date"] = brands.select("//span/text()").extract()[counter]
        counter=counter+1
        request = Request(url,callback=self.parse_model, meta={'item':item})
        yield request

def parse_model(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    models = sel.xpath("//*[@id='blocks-left']/div[1]/div/div[5]/p")
    for model in models:
        item = CraigslistSampleItem(response.meta["item"])
        item ['description'] = model.xpath("//*[@id='blocks-left']/div[1]/div/div[5]/p")[0].extract()
        yield item
```

The intended purpose of the above program is to read title, url, date from one page.. and using the read url, the **description** of some item should be scraped from url.
Could someone correct me to implement the logic to crawl nested pages in the same web site. It would be of great help if you could please share some working example for nested spider.

Comment: which is exactly the error? and you need to share the url you are crawling to check functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask for spider/crawler working example I share the [simple python crawler code](https://webscraping.pro/simple-email-crawler-python/). To me the crawling logic is simple there and thus easy to understand.

Comment: Hi, I would need the working example of crawling nested pages using Scrapy.. The one which you have shared is using BeautifulSoup..

Comment: @user3128771, how about [Scrapy crawl example](https://www.google.lv/search?num=100&newwindow=1&es_sm=122&q=Scrapy+crawl+example&oq=Scrapy+crawl+example&gs_l=serp.3..0i10j0i22i30l2.6592.9573.0.9820.3.3.0.0.0.0.753.1189.0j1j1j6-1.3.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.serp..0.3.1183.hz1b3CMG1Wk) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your spider code has (at least) two errors:

1. You use a CrawlSpider and the parse callback. Don't do that because documentation says this won't work [see the Warning](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules). Use the regular `Spider` instead.
2. You don't indent the `parse` blocks. Indent them.